# How to; Schema for fitness data ("Analytics")

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm currently working in renewing my fitness synchronisation product, and with it- the database logic/structure. I'm hoping to gain some expertise in the matter and how to think when this database becomes way bigger than it is today.

This is the setup today; About 15.000 active users, they are reporting (automatically through bracelets or apps) daily taken steps. I have two tables, 1) `steps`, 2) `steps_raw`.

table: `steps`
columns: `id`, `id_raw`, `user_id`, `source`, `steps`, `date`

table: `steps_raw`
columns: `id`, `user_id`, `source`, `steps`, `created`

The steps_raw-table stores all incoming data, and my script checks the data from the steps-table to see if there's been any change. E.g steps increase. If that's the case, update the `steps`-table. Either way, store the `raw`-data.

---

So, for this discussion; The new schema / structure should be able to store more fitness data than just steps. E.g "steps", "calories", "distance" and even more unknown right now, data types.

What I'm thinking is that I should have just one table instead, with one row per data type, per user, per date, per device (A user might have steps coming in from their Fitbit, iPhone and even some other app). And update those rows when incoming data (Skip the raw-data table) with a column for the raw-response (The rest-data that comes in from the API calls and so on).

That would mean that this table would become really big, rather quickly. One user might have 5 rows per day. And each time something get's pushed to the endpoint, update the potential already stored data (INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY...)

--- About the "Analytics" side of this;
I've seen that e.g Matomo Analytics has some sort of monthly aggregation functionality, where they takes all the raw data, and summaries it into a new generated table for that period (per month). And each user's data summaries into just one row, (from what I understand) e.g
`id`, `year`, `month`, `weekly_summary`, `monthly_summary` (Or something like that).

But since I care about which device that has been the one that has the highest reported data (Say that my Fitbit reports 5000 steps, and my iPhone reports 12000 steps, the iPhone-data is the one that will be used within my product).

-- So to my question; Do you guys have any ideas on how to think, and to do a more correct structure of everything so it could host alot more users than what I have today without striking any bottlenecks? I don't want to end up with a solution where I say "ops I forgot about that, it's a shame that I didn't store that kind of data to calculate that value..".

Thanks guys!

Comment: How many MB per day will come in?  What analytics do you want out?  Off hand, a daily summary seems optimal -- weekly, monthly, and annual can be easily derived from such.  Putting "raw" in JSON seems good an flexible, but hard to query.

Comment: Hello Rick, thank you for your questions! Right now, I don't store any raw json data, so the amount of mb are quite few. But when this column will be full, I would gess a couple of mb per day at least. Just to have something to count with, say 10-20mb of data per day.

I want to break out the most usable information from the raw data first, and put that data into columns (e.g having a column called "value" which represents "steps", "calories" and whatever we are counting followed by "distance", "duration")

Comment: Do each of these "values" have a "datetime" associated with them?  What do the ultimate queries look like?  Will they involve things like "total calories" and "steps per hour"?  Or maybe some type of graphing?  Recording the time of each "step" would need sub-second precision and lead to a huge amount of useless data.  What is useful is some summarization of that data -- perhaps "hh:mm, n steps", leaving out any minutes with zero steps.  And it may be best to do a summarization like this _before_ storing in the table you describe.

Comment: Im thinking that one column should keep all that raw data, coming from API's. The main row keeps the summary of the data (Total amount of steps, calories, distance, duration) but then one column with raw data. The raw data could keep information about the specifics ("steps per hour") - which I'd like to use when zooming into an activity (Showing graphs with activity per hour and so on)

Comment: Those sound like different "tables", not different "columns" or "rows".  Each "row" in a "table" should have similar data, but for a different time or user or product (etc).  Each column is a particular datatype (date, amount, name, raw JSON, etc).  Make new table when the rows and columns cannot conform to that pattern.

Comment: In your `steps` table, is `date` a DATE?  So each row is the summary for one user for one day?  But won't that be the summary of many "raw" messages?  That is, `id_raw` won't work for "one-to-many"

Comment: Hello, this is what Im thinking;

table: fitness_data, columns: `id`, `user_id`, `key`, `value`, `raw`, `date`

E.g usage: 
@1, 1, "steps", 10333, {}, "2021-09-08"@
@2, 1, "calories", 312, {}, "2021-09-08"@
@3, 1, "steps", 994, {}, "2021-09-09"@